# Print Window works locally, but NOT on site w/WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, printing, window

it works beautifully locally, but when I upload it to the WordPress site, the new print window opens and flashes on/off screen instantly. Only tested with Chrome and like I said, I have no problems 'til I upload it to the server?

Javascript:

```
function printDiv(divName) {

"use strict";
var divToPrint = document.getElementById(divName);

var WindowObject = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');
WindowObject.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html>');
WindowObject.document.writeln('<html><head><title>Your Safari Print Results</title>');
WindowObject.document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" id="fonts-googleapis-css"  href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%3A400%2C100%2C300%2C700%2C900&#038;ver=4.6" type="text/css" media="all">');
WindowObject.document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NewWinPrintScreen_hmap.css">');
WindowObject.document.writeln('</head><body onload="window.print()"><center><img src="logo.png" width="219" height="78"><br><div class="line"></div></center><br><br><span class="pg_title">Canine Wellness HealthMap</span>');

WindowObject.document.writeln(divToPrint.innerHTML);

WindowObject.document.writeln('</body></html>');

WindowObject.document.close();
setTimeout(function () { WindowObject.close(); }, 500);
```

}

EDITED THE ABOVE (Print Window Stays up now, but NO Content Showing in Chrome; Works in FF)

```
function printDiv(divName) {
```

"use strict";

```
var WindowObject = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');
var divToPrint = document.getElementById(divName);
WindowObject.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Your Safari Print Results</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/NewWinPrintScreen_hmap.css"></head><body><center><img src="images/logo.png" width="219" height="78"><br><div class="line"></div></center><br><br><span class="pg_title">Canine Wellness HealthMap</span>');
WindowObject.document.writeln(divToPrint.innerHTML);

WindowObject.document.writeln('</body></html>');

 /* Delaying the print event */ 
setInterval(function () {     }, 100);
  WindowObject.focus();
  WindowObject.print();
  WindowObject.close();
```

}

Comment: Not giving me any errors there. I played around with the script and got it the print window to stay up, but content is not in the preview and it prints blank. Working in Firefox though.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working correctly in Chrome. Opens print window, previews and closes afterwards. Between this code and ensuring jQuery is loaded, it's fully functional in Chrome now!

This Script Allows you to Print Multiple/Separate DIVs on the same page. Assign the print button to the DIV, and that's the DIV it will print!

```
function printDiv(divName) { // jshint ignore:line

"use strict";
var divToPrint = document.getElementById(divName);
var mywindow = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Your Safari Print Results</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/NewWinPrintScreen_hmap.css"></head>');
mywindow.document.write('<body><center><img src="images/logo.png" width="219" height="78"><br><div class="line"></div></center><br><br><span class="pg_title">Canine Wellness HealthMap</span>');

mywindow.document.write(divToPrint.innerHTML);

mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

setTimeout(function() { // wait until all resources loaded 
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.print(); // change window to winPrint
    mywindow.close(); // change window to winPrint
 }, 3000);
```

return true;
}

And for the Print Button Code (name your DIVs anything you like):

`<button onclick="Javascript:printDiv('Print-Needs-LifeStyle-Life-Stage')">Print</button>`

FYI: Changed 3000 to 500, because it was taking too long for the print preview window to come up after the New Window opened.